# Sort an array list of pathnames in java without comparator

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

My user input is

> \home\me\cs1
>
> \usr\share
>
> \var\log
>
> \usr\local\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib

and I need to sort these pathnames so that the output is in the correct lexographic order. However they are first sorted by length which is the number of slashes in each string. The path names are stored in an arraylist of strings. I attempting to do this without the use of collections,comparator or arrays. Would this be possible with the use of ArrayList?

the output should be:

> \usr\share
>
> \var\log
>
> \home\me\cs1
>
> \usr\local\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileName 
{
private ArrayList<String> pathNames;

public FileName()
{
    pathNames = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void printPaths()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pathNames.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(pathNames.get(i));
    }
}
public int pathLength(String path)
{
    int count = 0;
    String slash = "\\";
    for(int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++)
    {
        if(path.substring(i,i + 1).equals(slash))
        {
            count++;
        }   
    }
    return count;
}

public void sort()
{
    pathNames = mergeSort(pathNames);
}
public ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> paths)
{
    if(paths.size() == 1)
    {
        return paths;
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<String> left = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> right = new ArrayList<String>();
        int middle = paths.size() / 2;
        for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
        {
            left.add(paths.get(i));
        }

        for(int i = middle; i < paths.size(); i++)
        {
            right.add(paths.get(i));
        }

        right = mergeSort(left);
        left = mergeSort(left);

        merge(left, right, paths);
    }
    return paths;
}

public void merge(ArrayList<String> left, ArrayList<String> right, ArrayList<String> paths)
{
    int leftNum = 0;
    int rightNum = 0;
    int pathsNum = 0;
    while (leftNum < left.size() && rightNum < right.size())
    {
        if ((left.get(leftNum).compareTo(right.get(rightNum)))<0) 
        {
            paths.set(pathsNum, left.get(leftNum));
            leftNum++;
        }
        else
        {
            paths.set(pathsNum, right.get(rightNum));
            rightNum++;
        }
        pathsNum++;
    }

    ArrayList<String>rest;
    int restNum;
    if (leftNum >= left.size()) 
    {
        rest = right;
        restNum = rightNum;
    }
    else 
    {
        rest = left;
        restNum = leftNum;
    }

    for (int i = restNum; i < rest.size(); i++) 
    {
        paths.set(pathsNum, rest.get(i));
        pathsNum++;
    }

}
public void readInput()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a list of path names.(press enter after each path name, and type \"stop\" once you are finished.");
    String termination = "stop";
    String in = input.nextLine();
    boolean reading = true;
    while(reading)
    {
        pathNames.add(in);
        if(in.equals(termination))
        {
            reading = false;
            return;
        }
        in = input.nextLine();
    }
}
}
```

This is my main method.

```
public class FileNamePrgm 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        FileName paths = new FileName();
        paths.readInput();  
        paths.sort();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Implement a `Comparator` that compares the number of slashes, and pass it to the sort() method

Comment: Why don't you implement a Comparator?

Comment: You should use it, it is the most sensible thing to do. If it is homework, I cannot understand why they do not teach you it. You can still write a `mergeSort`using a `Comparator` tw.

Comment: The challenge is to write this code without using comparator but I don't understand how or why mine doesn't work

Comment: SO is not a debugging service :)  What is your output, where do you get the error, what did you try to do to debug it, etc...

Comment: when i enter "stop" the method continues to run. Which means the problem is in my readInput method but I don't see where.

Comment: If you got stuck while reading your input, why do you ask in the title, how to sort an arraylist?

Comment: because that is the main problem

Comment: Consider moving pathNames.add(in); after the termination check, cause as it is now, "stop" gets added to your pathnames.

Comment: Post your input file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
right = mergeSort(left);
```

Should be

```
right = mergeSort(right);
```

Also you need to add `in = input.nextLine();` once more inside the while loop. Currently you are reading only one line from the input and checking it over and over again.